# Angular routing doesnt work on CDN

Tags: angular, routes, cdn, azure-cdn

I have developed an angular 5 application. As angular produces plain javascript at the end i wanted to take advantage of that by hosting it on CDN. I have hosted the app on CDN but the issue is routing doesn't work.

i.e **www.mysite.com/index.html** works fine as that file is present on the CDN and all the navigation from this file using links or buttons works fine as well.

but if i try to call the URL directly that maps to angular route it doesn't work. i.e **www.mysite.com/register**

I know CDN only serves the static content present on their directory. Is there any way i can make this angular routing work?

I am using Azure CDN and my APIs are hosted on Azure as well.

Thanks

Comment: Can you post the real website? Which CDN you are using Verizon or Akamai

Comment: @ValentinPetkov Site is under development. I am planning to use Azure CDN.

Comment: Well my recommendation will be go with Azure Verizon CDN  there is SSL for custom domain and can set some rules... I use all Azure Verizon, Azure Akamai, Rackspace Akamai CDN, and Amazon CDN is much easy to implement for static web site but is more expensive than Azure Verizon a lot of hidden cost...